# checking the order and value equivalency within a python list

Tags: python-3.x, database, list, format

What would be a function where if 2 numbers are on the same order on a list it will print out the order of that number and the number itself. So in `list_1`  and `list_2` 21 is the 3rd value in the both of those lists So therefore results: `number:24 order:3`

```
list_1 =[27, 20, 22, 21, 17, 12, 24, 23, 19, 14, 11, 26, 25, 13, 15, 21, 18, 28, 29, 10]
list_2 = [14, 25, 26, 21, 22, 17, 11, 23, 27, 18, 24, 28, 12, 29, 16, 19, 13, 10, 20, 15]
```

Comment: Is the issue resolved? If so, please mark any of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate them together:

```
for i, j in zip(enumerate(list_1), enumerate(list_2)):
    if i == j:
        print("number:{} order:{}".format(i[1], i[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

@selcuk egese, would you try to these steps first:
And see if you can just figure it out - by looping and find the first matching?

```py
lst1_map = {i: x for i, x in enumerate(list_1)}
print(lst1_map)


lst2_map = {i: x for i, x in enumerate(list_2)}

print(lst2_map)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the zip function to do this and create a object like that:

```
[(list_1[0], list_2[0]), (list_1[1], list_2[1]), etc]
```

Then you can iterate over this object and verify if each item in each tuple are equals. Something like:

```
 for index, ziped in enumerate(zip(list_1, list_2)):
     if ziped[0] == ziped[1]:
         print(f"number: {ziped[0]} order {index}")
```

the enumerate() function is just to retrieve the order.